# NO + [RCTConvert MKCoordinateRegion:] function found

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Getting the following error when trying to access the screen (using react-native-navigation) in which I'm using `<MapView>`;

The project build phase passes successfully, and all other screens and functionalities work fine. The same screen (MapView Screen) works fine on Android. I am not using `cocoa-pods`, just did `manual linking`.

Unfortunately after finishing the `react-native-maps` implementation the following error occurs on IOS:

Error:

```
NO + [RCTConvert MKCoordinateRegion:] function found.
```

My Mac:

```
MAC: macOS High Sierra v 10.13.6,
```

My Xcode:

```
XCode Version: 9.4.1,
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "react": "16.6.3",
        "react-native": "0.57.8",
        "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
        "react-native-navigation": "^2.17.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0"
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I find out that relinking is the solution here, hope this helps somebody:

```
react-native unlink react-native-maps

react-native link react-native-maps
```